# Redirect 301 wp url based on year/month/day to post-name.html

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, permalinks

I recently changed the permalink structure from

https://www.domainName.ro/2018/04/10/post-name.html

to

https://www.domainName.ro/post-name.html,

using:

`"RedirectMatch rule 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ https://www.domainName.ro/$4.html"` and works.

Now I want to redirect, within the same site (old URL), the URLs from

https://www.domainName.ro/2018/04/10/post-name/

to

https://www.domainName.ro/post-name.html

I tried different rules and did not work.
The two rules must work at the same time on the site

Can you help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried this rule: <<RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.domain.ro/$3.html >> and got this: <<https://www.domain.ro/post/.html>> Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the url using wordpress plugin called redirection after install the plugin you can simply add url which you need to redirect from old to new just simple go to tools and there you find redirection click on that and you will find 2 box in 1box you need to enter old url which you need to redirect and 2box you need to enter new url where you need to redirect and click on save and you are done redirecting

Hope this will work for you

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)